# Can I compile Traceur into one file? (including runtime for classes)

Tags: javascript, traceur

I was attempting to use Traceur for a few small client-side micro libraries that I maintain. I would like to refactor them to use "classes" and a few other ES6 features and then compile an es5 version for production.

However, once I add classes the compiled out requires the runtime which is really big for all I need (just extending constructor functions). Is there a way to configure it so that it puts just what it needs to run into one file like CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own runtime by following the recipe in the Makefile and omitting the files you don't need. traceur is 'self-hosted' so you use the ./traceur command with inputs and flags to create an output file which is the runtime source. Start with `make bin/traceur-runtime.js` then whittle down the files until you have what you need.

We are working on an automated way to do this, but it's not likely to be done soon.